# Inspect docker image in google-artifact-registry

Tags: docker, google-artifact-registry

Using Docker image inspect on images store in google cloud artifact registry.

So I want to use the following command

```
docker image inspect --format='{{json .Config.Labels}} myimage
```

on an image in artifact registry to get the labels of the image. I try different things but nothing works yet. Do you have any idea to do it, instead of pulling the image to local?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.repositories.dockerImages/get

Answer (score 0):

There are several standalone tools to inspect content on registries without pulling the image. The three main ones I'm aware of are Google's crane, RedHat's skopeo, and my own regclient.

```bash
crane config nginx:latest
skopeo inspect --config docker://nginx:latest
regctl image inspect nginx:latest
```

Note that labels are not the same as annotations. If you want the annotations, you need to view the manifest, not the image config (each of these tools can do that, and docker also has `docker buildx imagetools inspect`).